# Where are the az role assignments listed

Tags: azure, azure-cli

I assigned a Service Principal to a VNET with

`az role assignment create --assignee SP_CLIENT_ID --scope VNET_ID --role Contributor`

Where can I review the configuration (Azure portal or cli)?

Update: I was looking for the subnets roles assignment which are a bit hidden under: vNet > Subnets > Managed users > Role assignments.

Comment: IAM blade under that specific vNet? We use service connections to deploy and configure all our resources and these service principals are being assigned a role and are visible under the IAM blade.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Where can I review the configuration (Azure portal or cli)?

1.Use Azure portal:

Navigate to the vnet in the portal -> `Access control (IAM)` -> `Role assignments` -> search for the name of your service principal like below.

[image]

2.Use Azure CLI:

```
az role assignment list --assignee SP_CLIENT_ID --scope VNET_ID
```

[image]

Comment: Ah I see, the scope has to be absolute, I thought it would list child resources as well.

Comment: @Yannick yes, vnet and subnet have different resource ids.

Comment: Is there a way to find all roles assigned to an App/client, without providing the scope?

Comment: @Yannick Yes, you can, just use `az role assignment list --assignee SP_CLIENT_ID `.

Comment: I get an empty list, weird

Comment: @Yannick Use `az account set --subscription <subscription-id>` to make sure you are using the correct subscription.

Comment: @JoyWang, same here.

Comment: @Yannick I tried even setting subscription. Still getting empty list.

Comment: Add --include-groups so you scan the group permissions recursively as well.

Answer (score 1):

For future readers, if you tried to use Joy's answer to query for *all* roles assigned to a Managed Identity, and you're unexpectedly receiving an empty array, try adding the `--all` switch.

EX: `az role assignment list --assignee '<PRINCIPAL_ID>' --all`

The relevant docs are [here](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs/blob/main/articles/role-based-access-control/role-assignments-list-cli.md#list-role-assignments-for-a-managed-identity).